# How to profile the time it's taking Terminal to process and source .bash_profile/.bachrc?

Tags: bash, macos, unix, terminal

I recently stumbled on a interesting way to split up your `.bash_profile` or `.bashrc` file on Medium (https://medium.com/@waxzce/use-bashrc-d-directory-instead-of-bloated-bashrc-50204d5389ff).

After doing this though, I was curious to see if the startup time for `bash` was affected positively or negatively. I know on **Windows 10**, `PowerShell` throws out the time it took to source the profiles and stuff, every time it starts; but I was wondering if there was a way of doing that for `bash` in **MacOS**?

Better yet, how would someone go about testing and profiling their `.bash_profile` /`.bashrc` setup?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here, you could rename the `.bash_profile` file to `.bash_profile.bak` and the `.bashrc` file to `.bashrc.bak`. Then, create a new file named `.bashrc` and put the following inside:

```
time source .bash_profile.bak
time source .bashrc.bak
```

Afterwards, the amount of time it takes to load each should be printed to the console upon opening a terminal emulator. If you want to undo this, just delete `.bashrc` and rename each of the `.bak` files to their respective previous names.